# Story starting with the Siege Perilous

Tags: story-identification

I believe I've read three stories that all started with characters from the modern world, or something much like it, sitting on the legendary [Siege Perilous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_Perilous) and being transported to another world. The first is Andre Norton's *Witch World* the first book in that saga and I thought that the second was Stephen R. Donaldson's *Lord Foul's Bane* the first in The Chronicles of Thomas Covenant but Zeiss Ikon pointed out I was wrong about that. I remember that the story I'm looking for started with a man on the run from unspecified difficulties being offered the use of the Siege Perilous as an avenue of escape and being transported to another world, I seem to recall he arrives in a desert but I'm not sure of that. I read the story 20+years ago but I think it was originally published in the 1960s-1980s though it may have been contemporary to the late 90s.

Comment: I don't recall the Siege Perilous appearing in *Lord Foul's Bane* -- that world shift was tied to a prophetic vagrant who needed CPR, as I recall.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Oh bother, you are quite right, now I'm looking for two stories that start with the Siege Perilous and I'm almost certain one is a conflation of some sort. There's a vagrant and an emergency services vehicle in Lord Foul's Bane it's not clear if they are related by more than happenstance.

Comment: The vagrant was the "god" of the alternate world, as I recall.  I don't recall an EMS vehicle, but I haven't reread the book since the year it came out.

Comment: @ZeissIkon To be honest I never got particularly far with Thomas Covanant, I had to reread the start of it to check what happened; I could have sworn that was the second story but apparently not.

Comment: The second *trilogy* involved a companion crossing worlds with Covenant, after he'd been stabbed in the chest.  I haven't reread the books -- too depressing to get through a second time.  I bought and read them when each came out, and never again since.

Comment: "[A] man on the run from unspecified difficulties being offered the use of the Siege Perilous as an avenue of escape and being transported to another world," is exactly the beginning of *Witch World*, except that the difficulties are only *mostly* unspecified.

Comment: @Buzz Yes that's why Witch World is listed as the story I'm sure it's not.

Comment: @ZeissIkon & Ash there's Stephen King's "Gunslinger" where Jake and other characters get transported to the Gunslinger's world - Jake into the desert after being pushed in front of a train(?), but IIRC (after 10ish years) the others get transported to a beach via a door in a house, and Jake comes back somehow later in the series after being killed in the first book. I don't think siege perilous is mentioned, but it has been quite some time since I read the series.

Comment: No Siege Perilous, but the beginning of Almuric by Robert E Howard is very similar..."THE TRANSITION was so swift and brief, that it seemed less than a tick of time lay between the moment I placed myself in Professor Hildebrand’s strange machine, and the instant when I found myself standing upright in the clear sunlight that flooded a broad plain. I could not doubt that I had indeed been transported to another world."